# Returning substrings depending on preceding string

Tags: python, substring

May be a little too many for today.. but meh.

This problem is pretty confusing to me. This function takes a list of strings as a parameter and returns every string that is a substring of the one that precedes it. So

1. ["hope", "hop", "hopefully", "test", "testing"] will return ['hop']
2. ["hopefully", "hope", "hop", "testing", "test"] will return ['hope', 'hop', 'test']

Excuse the mess of code here, I'm still learning.

```
def findSubStrs(lst):
'list ==> list, return list of all strings that are substrings of their predecessor in lst'
res = []
for a in lst:
    if len(int(a-1)) > len(lst):
        res = res + [a]
return res
```

I figured that len(int(a-1)) would work to check the preceding string, but I just got the error message "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'" The only result I found that worked was len(a) < 3 or some other int, but that doesn't return everything I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how bout

```
print [my_list[i] for i in range(1,len(my_list)) if my_list[i] in my_list[i-1]]
```

for example

```
>>> def findSubStrs(my_list):
...     return [my_list[i] for i in range(1,len(my_list)) if my_list[i] in my_list[i-1]]
>>> findSubStrs(["hope", "hop", "hopefully", "test", "testing"] )
['hop']
>>> findSubStrs(["hopefully", "hope", "hop", "testing", "test"])
['hope', 'hop', 'test']
```

to do this without a list comprehension you can just use a simple loop

```
for i in range(1,len(my_list)):
    if my_list[i] in my_list[i-1]:
        print my_list[i]
```

Comment: This actually worked perfectly, thank you. How would I write that so it's not in list comprehension form, however? I think at this point it'd be easier for me to actually understand it that way.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. I understand it much better now.

Comment: the zip solution is nice because you dont have to worry about indices and list lengths ...

Answer (score 5):

You can use `zip` to get the pairs to compare:

```
>>> s1 = ["hope", "hop", "hopefully", "test", "testing"]
>>> [b for a,b in zip(s1, s1[1:]) if b in a]
['hop']
>>> s2 = ["hopefully", "hope", "hop", "testing", "test"]
>>> [b for a,b in zip(s2, s2[1:]) if b in a]
['hope', 'hop', 'test']
```

As for your code:

```
res = []
for a in lst:
    if len(int(a-1)) > len(lst):
        res = res + [a]
return res
```

This will loop over every element in `lst`.  `len(int(a-1))` will try to subtract 1 from a string, and then convert the result to an integer, and then take the length of an integer, and after that you compare that length to the length of the list `len(lst)`.  That isn't what you want.  (Another answer has already explained the right way to do this using loops and indices, so I'll stop.)

Comment: gj explaining what was wrong with OP code (TBH it was hard to tell that that code was meant to solve the problem at hand...)